# Drupal 7 module recommendations for mailman listserv?

Tags: 7

From what I've seen the only mailman integration module is [Mailman Manager](http://drupal.org/project/mailman_manager) which is only D6.

Does anyone know of another module or any other tool that I could use to implement the same functionality for D7? I.e.:

- administer the lists
- allow users to subscribe
- unsubscribe
- etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try http://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews .. i personally use mailchimp with the drupal mail chimp module drupal.

Comment: Thanks duckx. I'm sorta stuck with mailman, so I can't easily switch to any other mail modules...

Comment: why not just import all that data out.

Comment: My client is worried about changing it up... sigh... thanks for your help though. I think your answer is unfortunately the only answer I will find since mailman is becoming a relic.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jul 19, 2013, there is a [7.x-1.0-RC1](https://www.drupal.org/node/2045663) release of the module in the questionavailable. As of today, it seems to be used (= reported installs) in 28 D7 sites, which is about 11% of the total number of sites (255).

In its issue queue there are 3, out of 71 issues related to D7 ... 1 specific one is [issue # 2043971](https://www.drupal.org/node/2043971).

That makes me wonder if it's yes or no worth giving that RC1 version a try these days ...